# Passing List of Exception Types as type parameter to generic method

Tags: c#, generics, exception

I'm trying to write a generic helper method that'd call methods and handle exceptions if any.

The method should be able to accept a `List` of acceptable `Exception` types, and handle them in a specific way. For other type of exceptions, it'll handle differently.

This is a very simplified version of the method

```
public static TResult InvokeMethod<TResult, TAllowedException>
                (Func<TResult> func) where TAllowedException : Exception
{
    try
    {
        return func();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (ex is TAllowedException) //do something
            return default(TResult);
        else //do something else
            throw;
    }
}
```

Here I'm specifying the **allowed Exception Type** as `TAllowedException`. This works fine. But, this accepts only a single `Exception_Type`. How can I pass a `List<Exception_Type>` instead?

Comment: What problem are you having with passing a `List<Exception>`? Its not clear exactly what you are after...

Comment: @Chris I do not want to pass a list of Exception objects, I need to pass a list of Exception Types. A `List<Exception>` would be a list of Exception objects/instances.

Comment: Ah yeah. I was thinking `List<Type>` but said `List<exception>`. Or are you not familiar with using the `Type` class?

Comment: @Chris then the `Type`(s) could be any `Type` and inside the method I have to validate if the Types are Exception Types. I want to restrict those Types to Exception Types. Any help on that?

Comment: I don't think there is anything more than the obvious code. You could create a class that you use to add or remove exceptions from your list and validate them as you do but I can't think of any way you could do it with generics or anything like that (and I'm assuming you don't have control of the exceptions so can't just stick interfaces on them). Sorry I can't help more.

Comment: @Chris I might end up doing something similar. Thanks for the efforts, it does help to think of different approaches :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot pass a list of types as type arguments to a generic method.

Why not simply pass a collection of types as a regular parameter?

```
public static TResult InvokeMethod<TResult>
        (Func<TResult> func, ICollection<Type> ignoredExceptions)
{
    try
    {
        return func();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)                         
        when (ignoredExceptions != null &&                    
              ignoredExceptions.Any(t => t.IsAssignableFrom(ex.GetType())))
    {
        return default(TResult);
    }
}
```

If someone passes a `Type` that is not an exception, nothing bad will happen. In my opinion there is no need to validate it. The method will still work correctly - the exceptions in the collection will be ignored.

What is the expected behavior of calling `InvokeMethod(func, new Type[] { typeof(Int32) })`? The `func` will be executed, and if it throws an exception that is an `Int32`, the default result will be returned. `func` will never throw an `Int32` exception, so it already works like that without validating `ignoredExceptions`.

BTW passing `arg` as a parameter is not necessary. You can use a lambda to capture `arg` in a closure - `() => func(arg)`. And this will work with any number of arguments.

**Edit**

If you really want to restrict the types at compile time, you'd have to create your own collection, with a bit weird generic `Add` method:

```
public class ExceptionCollection : IEnumerable<Type>
{
    private readonly List<Type> _exceptions = new List<Type>();        

    public void Add<T>() where T : Exception => _exceptions.Add(typeof(T));
    public IEnumerator<Type> GetEnumerator() => _exceptions.GetEnumerator();
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => ((IEnumerable)_exceptions).GetEnumerator();
}
```

The biggest disadvantage of this class is that it doesn't work with collection initializers.

There is a way to make it work with collection initializers too. The initializers require an `Add` method taking one parameter, but they will happily work with a generic `Add<T>(T item)` method.

```
public void Add<T>(T item) where T : Exception => _exceptions.Add(typeof(T));
```

Using it is a bit tricky too. We could of course pass instances of exceptions, but it's pointless to create an instance only to get its type. We can pass a strongly-typed `null` instead, using a cast or `default(T)`:

```
new ExceptionCollection { default(ArgumentNullException), default(ArgumentException) };
```

I still think that in this particular case it's not necessary to validate the collection of types. There might be other cases when a constrained collection of types is necessary - then the above solution is quite ok.

Comment: I though of this and probably I'll use this as the last resort. I was wondering if I could restrict the `Type`s to `Exception`s as a rule! And yes, you are correct on [1] no need to check type [2] the closure part. +1

Comment: I'm actually using a modified version of your edited answer. Thanks for the help.